# I'm trying to do an exercise from the book :Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++ (Second Edition)

Tags: c++

> Write a program that prompts the user to enter three integer values, and then outputs the values in numerical sequence separated by commas. So, if the user enters the values 10 4 6, the output should be 4, 6, 10. If two values are the same, they should just be ordered together. So, the input 4 5 4 should give 4, 4, 5.

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter three integer values seperated by a space (press 'enter' when done):\n";   //prompt
    int val1, val2, val3 = 0;
    cin >> val1 >> val2 >> val3;
    if (val1 <= val2 && val2 <= val3)
    {
        cout << val1 << ", " << val2 << ", " << val3 << "\n";
    }
    if (val1 >= val2 && val2 >= val3)
    {
        cout << val3 << ", " << val2 << ", " << val1 << "\n";
    }
    if (val2 <= val3 && val3 <= val1)
    {
        cout << val2 << ", " << val3 << ", " << val1 << "\n";
    }
    if (val3 <= val1 && val1 <= val2)
    {
        cout << val3 << ", " << val1 << ", " << val2 << "\n";
    }
    if (val1 <= val3 && val3 <= val2)
    {
        cout << val1 << ", " << val3 << ", " << val2 << "\n";
    }
    if (val2 <= val1 && val1 <= val3)
    {
        cout << val2 << ", " << val1 << ", " << val3 << "\n";
    }
}
```

The program works for all values. The only problem I am running into is: when I enter repeated values such as *2 2 3* I'll receive the output 2, 2, 3 twice instead of once. I'm sorry I did not comment any of the lines. It seems self explanatory enough and I don't know what I'd comment.

Comment: You should use `else if` statements after the first if statement.

Comment: this is a good opportunity to use a debugger. If you step through your code line by line you will see which two conditions evaluate to `true` and where the output is coming from

Answer (score 2):

Keeping your logic, you should use `else if`:

```
if (val1 <= val2 && val2 <= val3)
{
    cout << val1 << ", " << val2 << ", " << val3 << "\n";
}
else if (val1 >= val2 && val2 >= val3)
{
    cout << val3 << ", " << val2 << ", " << val1 << "\n";
}
else if (val2 <= val3 && val3 <= val1)
{
    cout << val2 << ", " << val3 << ", " << val1 << "\n";
}
else if (val3 <= val1 && val1 <= val2)
{
    cout << val3 << ", " << val1 << ", " << val2 << "\n";
}
else if (val1 <= val3 && val3 <= val2)
{
    cout << val1 << ", " << val3 << ", " << val2 << "\n";
}
else if (val2 <= val1 && val1 <= val3)
{
    cout << val2 << ", " << val1 << ", " << val3 << "\n";
}
```

but can be simplified to

```
int values[3];

for (int& value : values)
    std::cin >> value;
std::sort(std::begin(values), std::end(values));
const char* sep = "";
for (int value : values) {
    std::cout << sep << value;
    sep = ", ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: I appreciate you; thanks for your help Jarod42. I want to make sure I understand your reasoning for adding else if. Is it because once it finds a true "if/else if"statement it will skip all other lines of code following it?